# How to write a function that will subtract the mean value for each column in one dataset from each value of the synonymous column in another?

Tags: r, string, function, for-loop

I have a test dataset (A) and a control dataset (B) containing several variables with the same names e.g.

```
groupA <- data.frame(var1 = runif(100, 10, 50), 
                         var2 =runif(100,0,20), 
                         var3 =runif(100,50,200),
                         var4 =runif(100,1,10),
                         var50 = runif (100, 25, 75))

groupB <-  data.frame(var1 = runif(2000, 0, 20), 
                          var2 =runif(2000,0,5), 
                          var3 =runif(2000,10,100),
                          var4 =runif(2000,0,4),
                          var50 = runif (2000, 10, 40))
```

I want to write a function that will subtract the mean value in the control group from each value in the test group, e.g.

```
diff_from_ctrl = function(test_group, ctrl_group) {
  
  ctrl_means = ctrl_group %>% summarise_if(is_numeric, funs(mean), na.rm=TRUE)                          

  vars = colnames(test_group)[colnames(test_group) %in% colnames(ctrl_group)]
  
  for (i in vars) {
  
   assign(paste("test_group$", i, "_difference", sep=""), test_group$i - ctrl_means$i)
     
  }
  
return(test_group) 
   
}
```

But if I try:

```
print(diff_from_ctrl(groupA, groupB))
```

I get the original groupB back:

```
      var1       var2      var3     var4    var50
1   14.29821 13.5228020 137.98966 5.202536 64.20933
2   15.05122 11.1344435  94.12629 2.092474 45.31447
3   15.93575 10.2768177 181.30082 4.967360 41.91681
4   39.59778 16.5305678 142.23223 1.566413 28.28499
```

How do I get this (or something with the same effect) to work?

Comment: Maybe try `scale(groupA, center = colMeans(groupB[names(groupA)]), scale = FALSE)`

Comment: Or maybe you need `groupA - as.list(colMeans(groupB[names(groupA)]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes in your function:

```
#Function
diff_from_ctrl = function(test_group, ctrl_group) {
  
  ctrl_means = ctrl_group %>% summarise_if(is_numeric, funs(mean), na.rm=TRUE)                          
  
  vars = colnames(test_group)[colnames(test_group) %in% colnames(ctrl_group)]
  
  d = data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = nrow(test_group),ncol = length(vars)))  
  
  for (i in 1:length(vars)) {
    name <- paste0(vars[i],"_difference")
    d[,i] <- test_group[[vars[i]]] - ctrl_means[[vars[i]]]
    names(d)[i] <- name
  }
  
  return(d) 
  
}
#Apply
print(diff_from_ctrl(groupA, groupB))
```

Output:

```
    var1_difference var2_difference var3_difference var4_difference var50_difference
1         33.203310      4.94292895       94.491952       3.4840740       41.6003025
2         19.169198     11.81084845       48.142470       1.7567718       19.6835084
3          7.802682      9.68355685       64.760076      -0.3099979        3.4346186
4          8.300135     15.82293590       22.645086       7.4751334       29.1544858
5         17.506229      2.38881184      136.931842       4.4316549       41.7158364
6         29.225913     16.92536073      121.163336       7.8856150       30.1821779
7         28.133587      0.08699649       89.633183       6.7447759        4.8105073
8         17.036099     12.46772899       -2.402515       7.2570275       23.9059036
9         24.353676      5.60327501      130.130715       4.7939477       33.3312953
10        23.030570     -1.58794525      137.290606       5.1321267       25.7086459
11        17.275657     10.52145595       55.349376       5.2674844       15.4872430
12        12.956733     10.17578459      141.964816      -0.8020762        7.2208547
13        33.861686     15.02341122      110.429916       6.7858590       21.2687067
14        18.520001      5.47782768      140.594292       2.4680543        2.8744303
15        38.651643      8.64855272       25.430119       7.9524238        7.6491519
16         8.077864     17.33503734       33.511336       2.8073960       39.6877949
17        34.305928     16.63833198       26.881291       6.5902189       20.1892286
18        25.437010     12.88889116      136.893056       4.3218051       42.6008728
19        32.630974     -2.01720458       73.185552       6.8449591       45.1812504
20        29.267502     16.37226297       85.964597       5.4608599       32.5182852
21         4.127230      5.75062064      142.053007       0.9912049       31.6778494
22        32.359114      1.71553968       -2.057777       6.7112883        0.6149238
23        28.847416      0.81083092       94.996353       4.8748762       35.7693921
24        38.033854     13.46092419        8.559961       6.9431893       35.8254111
25        13.283702     -0.76796724       52.619622       0.4142543       45.5555365
26        38.587406      8.08513357      114.880630       0.4069133       38.7975086
27        31.284807     15.06786357       51.995986       6.7411003        5.1285692
28         4.509920      7.75710025      125.160986       7.6916616       12.4031193
29         9.930233      8.14259466      124.162447       6.0142757       34.2400434
30        28.111750     10.77904153       73.097862       4.8621635       16.6333425
31        20.959735      9.13934337       85.145484       2.2834130       14.6180899
32        38.055072     14.15901639       84.731298       2.7372607        6.9879907
33        13.848445      4.09122105       93.066361       0.8153527       31.7265467
34        23.830714      7.81382320      125.543401       4.0896427       40.3456334
35         4.344116      3.00662400      125.691867       3.7892435       25.4646406
36         4.319042      6.78341574      111.188280       4.0266966       18.8593718
37        32.810355      5.99720995       90.288058       7.6424969       23.9874598
38        35.767064     17.12209000      136.382728       4.9227308       25.1788358
39        15.178178     15.75455491       11.270672       3.8320581       18.0687782
40         9.012825     14.33210102       31.923819       3.9882355       46.9512614
41        23.471686     15.31132674      108.695686       6.2686661       14.6726047
42        20.393032     -0.83682346       11.336327       6.9968963       15.9254252
43        14.487152     10.92264758       87.077987       1.5567086        9.2207481
44        20.500681     10.01450190      136.135332       3.9812425       10.1546719
45        24.185730      8.05816730       71.615452      -0.8618480       26.3231948
46        30.055771     10.81264860        4.980374       7.4411233       47.8105301
47         1.786007      1.01525348      118.856779       3.0324028        2.7658655
48        29.426418      2.38177962      110.930748       4.9299260       19.2574724
49        38.378280      9.79318761      101.807412       3.9611784       17.9488621
50        26.620767      6.26229068       82.945029       2.8623011       27.7089569
51        14.614761      6.08863433       94.611087       1.6902279       24.2542327
52        17.780888      2.71641856       41.723542       3.3214109       13.3439278
53        34.308213     10.06443082       55.433711       1.0122311       13.1429395
54        35.248953      3.63100556      128.945667       0.2815480       24.2949771
55        38.517907     12.23287520       88.746145       6.9232249       49.0287364
56        34.401840     15.33192061       39.603343       2.8946158       -0.1317987
57         1.421372      3.36521338       77.040574       2.7667397       29.6197289
58         2.043872      7.85770486       35.152138       3.2059057       35.5558126
59        28.693844      6.28352687      127.268856       6.6071144       18.3561765
60         5.037014      2.29035064       27.175445       1.2141249       34.9105463
61         7.040293     10.75275585        1.569627       2.3970482       48.8618659
62        18.018942     13.03214588       30.213170       0.1141537        6.1051873
63        16.134444     15.82334133      111.953115       3.0546869       29.1715633
64        14.543385     -2.46305352      140.429976       0.8420386       31.3754429
65        21.841775      1.35960866       92.121866       5.4603323       38.3841854
66        34.991657     -0.33332001       37.173272       3.8313812       18.5801889
67        22.812643     15.48920608        6.438101       4.7820275       19.1393995
68        35.841717      4.06779587       91.626962       0.8740242        3.3042364
69        28.173588     -0.79477611      106.667595       4.5692715       15.0514757
70        26.056741     11.70198648       47.071526       4.2617012       31.7238652
71        31.880476     -1.48580425       91.009704       3.8685692       48.6558942
72         6.989305      1.48372462       70.418407       7.6873184       20.9202866
73         7.844467     12.80094396      128.891826       6.1103571        0.5546725
74        19.319431      5.36280844      142.385693       3.7712229        1.5691174
75        33.140788     12.02282190       37.628944       7.0365611       25.5660373
76         5.978150     -1.25801953       66.712042       6.8412091       17.3115488
77        20.729383     15.85454958       79.423000      -0.7056569       16.0796217
78        12.492538      4.19454923      133.556006       4.0911125        9.4737980
79        18.377299     15.75406837       27.666871       2.1538778       32.7965790
80        11.612761      1.03959869       73.694635       1.2663216       15.5256232
81         1.660321     13.81112631      115.347545       6.7964807        0.3790968
82        18.979781      8.42373745       36.833646       3.1128147       23.5741508
83         7.576248     11.68778117       43.774824       1.1085423       26.5479489
84        31.713451      4.68798206       86.201964       6.1894529       29.3732801
85        38.468290     -0.49851767       85.143065       7.3843204        6.8421319
86        37.946329      5.81187132       -2.770886       3.6357246       17.3716499
87        14.967304     12.12048976       63.370659       0.7798520        9.5766099
88         8.859785     15.42115414        9.080079       1.0025683       17.2981579
89        18.493987      9.94011568      127.045147       6.9882364       25.4506266
90        39.010062     -0.56847773      121.265689       4.9143828       33.0896392
91        25.619547      5.31526663       -4.898274       0.6259962       35.5761068
92         2.666727      6.05613550      115.172947       7.0874344       48.9203336
93        32.904048      4.30415268       49.225532      -0.8066808       26.0702031
94        32.509032     16.84020143       85.765646       6.7236941       40.7772914
95         3.041205     14.06438346       64.535848       4.5495793       15.5180681
96        36.218744      2.90629776       37.061841       7.7357446       36.1844467
97        23.140882     16.39081089       18.290245       5.6664721        6.1818288
98        31.229579      2.32855606       34.374184       3.3526870       32.9678201
99        21.950205      2.09805012       44.204091      -0.9757963       20.3643059
100        6.576897      3.59525943       31.701028       2.3952898       37.0055046
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well! I always get confused with string handling in R!

Comment: @Mel Great! Also be careful when you define the data structure. You were creating an empty dataframe so that the computed values were not assigned. With the adjust you will have an empty dataframe with values ready to be filled.